# Cloud Firebase Functions for push notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a function that once a document is changed a push notification will be sent to the user's mobile device. Here is the code for the function:

```
 exports.userProfileChanged = functions.firestore.document('/agents/{agentId}').onWrite( (change, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;

    console.log('A change has been made to user profile');

    // Get the user device token
    const getUserDeviceToken = db.document('/device/{agentId}').once('value');

    // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
    let deviceTokens;
    const results = Promise.all([getUserDeviceToken]);
    deviceTokens = results;

    if (deviceTokens == null) {
        return console.error('No device tokens found');
    }

    let title = "Changes have been made";
    let body = "changes have been made to your user profile";

    const payload = {
        notification: { title: title, body: body},
        token: snap.data().token,
        data: {click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' }
    };

    const response = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
    if (response.error) {
        console.error("Error sending message: ", response.error);
    } else {
        return console.log("Message sent successfully!");
    };
    
    return Promise.all(console.log('End of function'));
});
```

This is the error found in the function log in Firebase:
userProfileChanged
TypeError: db.document is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first initialize the database. That way, Firebase knows which database you're referring to.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

const db = admin.firestore()

exports.userProfileChanged = functions.firestore.document('/agents/{agentId}').onWrite( (change, context) => {
  // rest of your code
})
```

Now just a heads up, Firebase only allows you to call `admin.initializeApp()` once for all your functions. So it may be worth it to move that process to another file to reuse in all your functions.

```js
// admin.js

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.db = admin.firestore()
exports.admin = admin
```

```js
// user-profile-changed.js

const { db } = require('./admin')

exports.userProfileChanged = functions.firestore.document('/agents/{agentId}').onWrite( (change, context) => {
  // rest of your code
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am sorry for the confusion but I do initialize the database. I just didn't put it in my post. This is the line that I get the error message on:   const getUserDeviceToken = db.document('/device/{agentId}').once('value'); The functions log says: TypeError: db.document is not a function.  I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Also, I am looking for a good tutorial on writing js (for functions) and how to interact with the Firebase database. I have never used NoSql before. One thing I need is to be able to access single data elements but I would like to know more. Thanks

Comment: For the course, I'd highly recommend looking at https://fireship.io/. Jeff Delany (the creator) has tons of really clear courses on using Firebase. Several are free, but most are paid. You can get them all for $25 and for me, they're worth every cent. Not affiliated with him, just a customer. Alternatively, the Firebase YouTube channel has some great playlists that cover every detail of the Firebase platform.

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you so very much